# Perl Mechanize module for scraping pdfs

Tags: perl, web-crawler, www-mechanize

I have a website into which many pdfs are uploaded. What i want to do is to download all those PDFs present in the website. To do so i first need to provide username and password to the website. After searching for sometime i found WWW::Mechanize package that does this work. Now the problem arises here that i want to make a recursive search in the website meaning that if the link does not contain a PDF, then i should not simply discard the link but should navigate the link and check whether the new page has links that contain PDFs. In this way i should exhaustively search the entire website to download all PDFs uploaded. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: What you re trying to do sounds like a web spider. This module could be worth a look: http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/WWW-CheckSite-0.019_52/lib/WWW/CheckSite/Spider.pm

Answer (score 2):

I'd also go with `wget`, which runs on a variety of platforms.

If you want to do it in Perl, check CPAN for web crawlers.

You might want to decouple collecting PDF URLs from actually downloading them. Crawling already is lengthy processing and it might be advantageous to be able to hand off downloading tasks to seperate worker processes.

Comment: Add some concrete examples to your abstract advice.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about using `WWW::Mechanize` module. This module has a method - `find_all_links()` wherein you can point out the regex to match the kind of pages you want to grab or follow.

For example:

```
my $obj = WWW::Mechanize->new;
.......
.......
my @pdf_links = $obj->find_all_links( url_regex => qr/^.+?\.pdf/ );
```

This gives you all the links pointing to pdf files, Now iterate through these links and issue a get call on each of them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try with [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). Something like:

```
wget -r --no-parent -A.pdf --user=LOGIN --pasword=PASSWORD http://www.server.com/dir/
```

Comment: wget with the above options did not download the pdfs..it just downloaded .html files only..

Comment: It's strange. I just tried with `wget -r -A.pdf http://www.samplepdf.com/` and it just saves `sample.pdf` on my hd.